# How to draw a smooth path of bitmap,without any breaks

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

i am working on a paint application and i want to draw a path of bitmap 
my code is this:

```html
 private void onCanvasInitialization() {
  // Main_Activity.paintButton.setEnabled(true);

  mPaint = new Paint();
  BlurMaskFilter bmf = new BlurMaskFilter(2, Blur.OUTER);
  mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
  mPaint.setDither(true);
  mPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
  mPaint.setColor(Main_Activity.colorchanger);
  mCanvas = new Canvas();
  mPath = new Path();
  mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
 mPaint.setMaskFilter(bmf);
  mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
  mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
  mPaint.setAlpha(255);
  bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 30, 30, false);
  bmp = bmp.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
  super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
  mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

  mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
 }

 public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
  float x = event.getX();
  float y = event.getY();
  if (true)
   switch (event.getAction()) {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    touch_start(x, y);
    invalidate();
    break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    touch_move(x, y);
    invalidate();
    break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    touch_up();
    invalidate();
    break;
   }
  return true;
 }

 private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
  Random rand = new Random();
  float r = rand.nextFloat();
  float g = rand.nextFloat();
  float b = rand.nextFloat();
  Random rnd = new Random();
  mPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),
    rnd.nextInt(256)));

  mPath.reset();
  mPath.moveTo(x, y);
  mX = x;
  mY = y;
 }

 private void touch_move(float x, float y) {

  float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
  float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
  if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
   // mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);

   mX = x;
   mY = y;
   arrX[i] = mX;
   arrY[i] = mY;
   i++;
  }
 }


 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
   canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, arrX[k], arrY[k], mPaint);

  }
 }
```

by this i am able to draw bitmap on canvas but the flow is not smooth it is not looks like a line .there is a gap between the two successive bitmaps.i want it to look like a path .

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling **invalidate()** method in every **case:** , try to call it out ot switch.

For Ex.

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        if (true)
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);                   
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                break;
            }
          invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: OK...but it doesn't change anything